# How to assign $_POST['data'] to jquery variable

Tags: jquery, ajax, parameter-passing

I received data from a form to a new page like:

```
$id = $_POST['id']

$date = $_POST['date']
```

I use jQuery and ajax to process that posted data from last page and display the data on this new page where my jQuery and ajax running

```
function fetch_data()  
      {  
           $.ajax({  
                method:"POST",
                url: "process.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>&date=<?php echo $date; ?>",             
                success:function(data){  
                     $('#resultback').html(data);  
                }  
           });  
      }
```

Now, I use another function with ajax to delete `<tr>` from table in which it is the result from `process.php`. The delete function works fine but when I refresh the page the `function fetch_data()` runs again and put everything back because somehow the `$id & $date` still can be `echo` out or their value still is on the page. I think I need to know how can I pass `$_POST['any-data'] or $id/$date` to the jquery as a variable instead of using url->

```
 url: "process.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>&date=<?php echo $date; ?>"'
```

How can I pass those variable through jQuery and ajax and use `data:{}` inside ajax inside `function fetch_data()` to send data to `process.php` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the PHP variables into Javascript variables.

```
var id = <?php echo json_encode($id); ?>;
var date = <?php echo json_encode($date); ?>;
function fetch_data()  
  {  
       $.ajax({  
            method:"POST",
            url: "process.php?id=" + id + "&date=" + date,             
            success:function(data){  
                 $('#resultback').html(data);  
            }  
       });  
  }
```

You can reassign the `id` and `date` variables later, and they'll be used when you call `fetch_data()` again.